# Javascript Start setinterval after page loads

Tags: javascript

I have a script which displays seconds before showing hiding the div.

```
var seconds_left = 20;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "Or wait " + --seconds_left + " seconds to play the video.";
    if (seconds_left <= 0)
    {
    //alert('The video is ready to play.');
        $('#def').fadeOut('slow');
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

The problem is.. even the page is not fully loaded, the counting automatically starts.

What can i do to make the counting start after the page fully loaded?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't directly assign your onload, it will replace any existing onload. **Onload is used frequently so overriding it is a bad idea.** Do something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",yourFunction,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",yourFunction);
```

If you can **use a JS library like jQuery** it will probably make things easier for you. You can use

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Ref: https://ckon.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/stop-using-windowonload-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it in the `window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }`

**Example**

```
window.onload = function () {
    someFunction();
}


function someFunction() {
    var seconds_left = 20;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "Or wait " + --seconds_left + " seconds to play the video.";
        if (seconds_left <= 0) {
            //alert('The video is ready to play.');
            $('#def').fadeOut('slow');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It is just so that you don't sit with bloated code inside the onload method

Comment: ah i see what you are saying, my mistake i guess i copied it weird

Comment: it looks good now, removed my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can set an 'onload' event on your body tag, which runs as soon as your content finishes loading:

```
<body onload='yourFunction()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way if you really want to make sure your page is fully loaded:

```
 $(function() {
    // work when all HTML loaded except images and DOM is ready
 });

 $(window).load(function() {
    // this is come when complete page is fully loaded, including all  
    // frames, objects and images **/
 });
```

Use the load function for this problem I suggest you. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery do like this:

```
$(function(){
    //your code
});
```

And it's code will run after when page is loaded.